# Android setText in fragment does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments

in this sample code i want to custom message by setText but that doesnot work.

```
public class newCustomers extends Fragment {
    public newCustomers () {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_new_customers, container, false );
        final Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String currentDate = dateFormat.format ( date );
        String cDate1 = JalaliCalendar.g2j ( currentDate );

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_customers, container, false);
        EditText name = (EditText) view.findViewById ( R.id.name );

        String string="this is a text";
        name.setText ( string );
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume ();
    }
}
```

i'm wondering why thats dont work correctly. all of cast and my code is correct

Comment: you inflate two view in onCreatView and your editText is not in rootview that you have returned that, if you want see you need return view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your code:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_customers, container, false);
```

and make this edit in your code:

```
EditText name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById ( R.id.name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change return of `onCreateView` method to `view` instead of `rootView` :

```
name.setText ( string );
return view;
```

becuase you are access  `EditText` from `view` instead of `rootView`.